# Having trouble with scipy.integrate.tplquad

Tags: python, scipy

I am attempting to calculate the triple integral of an interpolator. The interpolator was formed using scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator with coords acting as the points and density acting as the values at said points (both displayed below).

```
print(coords)
[[  0.4   0.4 -15.6]
 [  1.2   0.4 -15.6]
 [  2.    0.4 -15.6]
 ...
 [ 14.   15.6  15.6]
 [ 14.8  15.6  15.6]
 [ 15.6  15.6  15.6]]
print(density)
0        7.174270e-08
1        6.809794e-08
2        6.130950e-08
3        5.234419e-08
4        4.247697e-08
             ...     
15995    0.000000e+00
15996    0.000000e+00
15997    0.000000e+00
15998    0.000000e+00
15999    0.000000e+00

#interpolator made as follows
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(coords, density)
```

The interpolator is acting as I want it to however when I attempt to evaluate

```
tplquad(interp, x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2)
```

(where x1, x2, ... are the limits of integration which I made sure are within the range in which I trust the interpolator to behave properly) the function never evaluates. I left it running for about 3 minutes and didn't get anything but I'm pretty positive it shouldn't take that long in the first place. I have a feeling the problem lies in the fact that I'm calling tplquad with an interpolator as the function but I'm unsure as this is my first time using this function, would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you provide details in order to make a [mcve] such as the actual grid used for interpolation? Does the problem exists when using Linear interpolation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/ND_regular_grid.html)? What happens if you increase the quadrature resolution tolerance to get a coarser result?

Comment: Does my solution answer your question? If it does, you can click the gray check next to my solution to accept it. If not, please clarify the issue.

Comment: @jared it didn't completely answer my question but led me in the right direction, I did end up getting an estimate of the integral using a Riemann integral but not in the form in which you suggested. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why not post your own answer then?

Comment: Wasn't aware I could, will do now.

Comment: @jared would appreciate your thoughts on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a simple example but with a double integral and it produced a result, but it was slow. So, it does work, but it's not quick. I suspect it is related to using a nearest-neighbor interpolator which results in a nonsmooth function that is difficult for scipy to integrate.

That said, because of your choice of interpolator, the integral can be computed using a Riemann integral (think about it in 1D: the nearest-neighbor method will find the closest x and return the value for that x, which creates many rectangles centered on the points). The integral is extremely simple if you have constant step sizes in all the dimensions, which it looks like you might have. Just compute `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` (i.e. the step sizes in each of the dimensions) and then the integral is

```py
integral = np.sum(dx*dy*dz*density)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion from @jared I ended up using a Riemann integral to get a
crude estimate for the integral. I am still looking for a better estimate but this is currently what I was able to come up with.

```
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(coords, density)

num_intervals = 200
dx = coords[:,0].max()/num_intervals
dy = coords[:,1].max()/num_intervals
dz = (coords[:,2].max()-coords[:,2].min())/num_intervals

x0 = 0
y0 = 0
z0 = coords[:,2].min()
integral = 0
for i in range(num_intervals):
  x0 += dx
  for j in range(num_intervals):
    y0 += dy
    for k in range(num_intervals):
        z0 += dz
        integral += interp(x0,y0,z0)
integral = integral*dx*dy*dz
```

Comment: I had made the assumption that `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` are the same for all points. Is that correct? If so, you can find those values using `dx = coords[1,:0] - coords[0,0]` (and similar for the other variables). As for your integration technique, I believe it will produce the same result as my method, assuming you have the same `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` values (which you should). Therefore, my approach would be better because it doesn't require a triple-nested `for` loop and is, therefore, more efficient. How do the values of the two methods compare?

Comment: @jared I think I wasn't clear in describing the goal of this procedure. I am trying to verify whether the interpolator is a probability density function and therefore attempting to see whether the integral of this interpolator over all its possible values is 1. This is the reasoning for adding the outputs from the interpolator rather than the density values themselves. I trust the interpolator the most over the range in which coords fills which is about a quarter of all its possible values. This is why the "limits of integration" are [xmin, xmax],... etc which would make dx,dy, and dz differe